# getClassHierarchy() method

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods

I have a superclass Person, which contains the following method:

```
public String getClasHierarchy()
{
  return "Person";
} //getClassHierarchy
```

I cannot change this class.

I also have 10 subclasses of person, which i need to add a similar method to in order to return a string consisting of the name of the class, followed by a ">" then followed by the string returned by getClassHierarchy() from the superclass. I can't rely on knowing what the class hierarchy above them is. Somehow, i need to invoke the method from the superclass. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have a look at the [`super` keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Comment: you said "i need to add a similar method", do you need to override the same method or is that going to be a new method?

Comment: I need to override the same method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the 'super' keyword

```
return super.getClassHierarchy() + ">MyClassName"
```

Anyway, this is best done by reflection rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I have added this to my subclasses, but when i compile and run the program, it still says "person" instead of "StudentWorker>Person".

Answer (score 0):

This is one way, there are lot other ways too.

```
public class TestClass extends TestClassSuper {

    public String getClasHierarchy() {
        System.out.println(super.getClasHierarchy());
        return "Person";
    } //getClassHierarchy

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            TestClass tc = new TestClass();
        System.out.println(tc.getClasHierarchy());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
}


public class TestClassSuper {

    public String getClasHierarchy() {

        return "Super Person";

    } //getClassHierarchy
}
```